# Detect case class in scala macro

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros, case-class, scala-2.11

Within a method being called as a scala (2.11) macro, is there a way to programmatically determine whether a `Type` is a `case class` or not?

The API for the method I'm working through boils down to this:

```scala
def typeIsCaseClass(c: Context)(targetType: c.universe.Type): Boolean = {
  // targetType "is case class?"
}
```

I'm open to altering the API if need be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The symbols usually contain all the interesting information:

```
def typeIsCaseClass(c: Context)(targetType: c.universe.Type): Boolean = {
  val sym = targetType.typeSymbol
  sym.isClass && sym.asClass.isCaseClass
}
```